# Why does by choosing an element $m\ne n+1: f(a_0) = m$ not guarantee immediately a bijective function between $A-\{a_0\} \mapsto S_{n+1}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I'm reading *Finite Sets* from *Munkres*' *Topology* where he discusses a lemma:

> **Lemma 6.1** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $A$ be a set; let $a_0$ be an element of $A.$ Then there exists a bijective correspondence $f$ of the set $A$ with $\{1 \ldots n+1\}$ if and only if there exists a bijective correspondence $g$ of the set $A-\{a_0\}$ with the set $\{1\ldots n\}\,.$

[image]

First the author assumes that $f(a_0) = n+1,$ then it's obvious that $f: A-\{a_0\}\mapsto \{1\ldots n\}\,.$

Now, if above is not the case, then  he lets $f(a_0) = m$ and $f(a_1)= n+1\,.$

Then he defines a new function $h$ and shows that it is bijective.

I'm having problem in comprehending the last part of the proof.

What is the point of letting $f(a_0) = m$ and $f(a_1) = n+1$ in defining $h$ and showing that $h$ is bijective?

Also, suppose $f(a_0) = m\in S= \{1\ldots n+1\};$ this means there are $n$ elements left in $S\,.$   Since $f$ was assumed to be bijective, won't that be obvious that $f: A-\{a_0\}\mapsto \{1\ldots n+1\}- \{m\}$ is a bijective correspondence? What is the necessity of defining another new function $h\,?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that a bijection $f\colon A\to B$ is a function whose domain is the entire set $A$, its range is the entire set $B$, and the function is injective.

If $f(a_0)=n+1$, then restriction $f$ to $A\setminus\{a_0\}$ does indeed provide us with a function whose range is $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. But if $f(a_0)=1$, for example, then restricting $f$ to $A\setminus\{a_0\}$ results in a function whose range is $\{2,\ldots,n+1\}$ instead.

It is true that $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $\{2,\ldots,n+1\}$ have the same size and there is an easy bijection between them. But you need to prove the statement that you want to prove, and the statement is to find a bijection with $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. So you might need to compose $f$ with a permutation of $A$ or of $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ to ensure that $f(a_0)=n+1$.

Comment: Firstly, thanks @Asaf for the answer; suppose $f: A\setminus \{a_0\}\mapsto \{2,\ldots, n+1\}$ and let $g: \{2,\ldots,n+1\}\mapsto \{1,\ldots,n\};$ so this means $g\circ f: A\setminus \{a_0\}\mapsto \{1,\ldots, n\}$ is a bijective correspondence. Is it right? If it is so, then why is the necessity to define another function $h\,?$ You said it is required to show the bijective correspondence between $A\setminus \{a_0\}$ and $S_{n+1};$ it seems I have done it without using $h.$ Am I right or wrong?

Comment: Yes, but then this composition is $h$. But you can also define a permutation of $A$, and compose it with $f$ (in the other direction, of course) to achieve the same result. Which is what the proof is doing. Now, note that you haven't defined what is $g$, in your comment, and you need to tell me what it is in the general case, not just when $f(a_0)=1$.

Comment: Thanks @asaf for the last comment; I did get the last comment of yours - the composition I defined in my first comment is actually mapping $a_0$ to $n+1$ and yes, $g$ is not defined; but Munkres defined $h$ in terms of  $f$ precisely.

Comment: Yes, defining $h$ in terms of $f$ is fine; but your $g$ is not defined. Period. You claim it exists, and surely it does, but you need to prove that. And the simplest way to actually prove that is to literally define the function. Moreover, if you want to take a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$, you might have to also prove its existence in a more complicated way. So it's slightly easier to just define $h$ directly.